# Checking name of last worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check the name of the last worksheet and see if it equals `"Field_10"` . If it does, I don't want it to do anything but if it doesn't, I want to add new worksheets.

**Expected output when there is only one sheet titled "Sheet1":**
Outputs "Adding new sheets" and adds ten new sheets titled Field_1 all the way up to Field_10.

**Expected output when the sheets (Field_1,..., Field_10) have already been added:**
Outputs "New sheets already added" and exits if statement.

I've included `MsgBox`es to help with debugging. The problem is, whether or not I check if the last sheet name is EQUAL to "Field_10" or NOT EQUAL to "Field_10", it always outputs "New sheets already added".

```
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheet.Count).Name = "Field_10" Then
    'If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheet.Count).Name <> "Field_10" Then
        MsgBox ("New sheets already added")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Adding new sheets")
        On Error Resume Next
        For h = 1 To 10
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Field_" & CStr(h)
        Next h
    End If
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typo in first line? `Worksheet.Count` should be `Worksheets.Count`

Comment: @chrisneilsen What a ridiculous mistake. Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below sub:

```
    Sub AddSheets()
    Dim NewSheetNo As Integer

        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Field_10" Then
           MsgBox ("New sheets already added")
        Else
           MsgBox ("New sheets are being aded...")
            On Error Resume Next
            For NewSheetNo = 1 To 10
                Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Field_" & NewSheetNo
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```